# KOMA-script list of listings and LOF have unequal space below heading

Tags: table-of-contents, listings, koma-script, vertical-spacing

I observed some unexpected behaviour with scrbook class (xelatex) and the list of listings from the `listings` package. The spacing between the chapter headings of the LOF and list of listings and the first entries of each list are not the same. The listings package produces a much bigger gap even without customising the appearance of chapter headings like in the MWE. Has anybody an idea what the problem could be and how to fix it? Thanks!

MWE:

```
\documentclass[
    10pt,
    oneside,
    listof=totoc,
    bibliography=totoc,
]{scrbook}

\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{listings}

\setkomafont{chapter}{\Large\bfseries\MakeUppercase}
\renewcommand*{\chapterheadstartvskip}{\vspace*{-\topskip+2pt}}

\begin{document}
\listoffigures
\listoftables
\lstlistoflistings
\chapter{A Chapter}
\begin{figure}
    \centering\includegraphics[width=0.5\linewidth]{example-image}
    \caption{First figure}
\end{figure}
\begin{table}
    \caption{First table}
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}[width=0.5\linewidth]{ccc}
        Cell 1 & Cell 2 & Cell 3
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\begin{lstlisting}[caption={First listing}]
    Some code
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two warnings in the log file of your code:

> Class scrbook Warning: `\float@listhead` detected!
> Implementation of `\float@listhead` became
> deprecated in KOMA-Script v3.01 2008/11/14 and
> has been replaced by several more flexible
> features of package `tocbasic`.
> Maybe implementation of `\float@listhead` will
> be removed from KOMA-Script soon.
> Loading of package `scrhack` may help to
> avoid this warning, if you are using a
> a package that still implements the
> deprecated `\float@listhead` interface on input line 18.

and

> Class scrbook Warning: `\float@addtolists` detected!
> Implementation of `\float@addtolist` became
> deprecated in KOMA-Script v3.01 2008/11/14 and
> has been replaced by several more flexible
> features of package `tocbasic`.
> Since Version 3.12 support for deprecated
> `\float@addtolist` interface has been
> restricted to only some of the KOMA-Script
> features and been removed from others.
> Loading of package `scrhack` may help to
> avoid this warning, if you are using a
> a package that still implements the
> deprecated `\float@addtolist` interface.

Load package `scrhack` as suggested in the warnings

```latex
\documentclass[
    10pt,
    oneside,
    listof=totoc,
    bibliography=totoc,
]{scrbook}
\usepackage{scrhack}% <- added

\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{listings}

\setkomafont{chapter}{\Large}
\RedeclareSectionCommand[
  beforeskip=\dimexpr-\topskip+2pt\relax,
  afterindent=false
]{chapter}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\chapterlinesformat[3]{%
  \@hangfrom{#2}{\MakeUppercase{#3}}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\listoffigures
\listoftables
\lstlistoflistings
\chapter{A Chapter}
\begin{figure}
    \centering\includegraphics[width=0.5\linewidth]{example-image}
    \caption{First figure}
\end{figure}
\begin{table}
    \caption{First table}
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}[width=0.5\linewidth]{ccc}
        Cell 1 & Cell 2 & Cell 3
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\begin{lstlisting}[caption={First listing}]
    Some code
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

[image]