# KOMA script etoc package changes vertical spacing between TOC heading and entries

Tags: koma-script, vertical-spacing, parskip, etoc

Based on the question [KOMA-script list of listings and LOF have unequal space below heading](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/640573/koma-script-list-of-listings-and-lof-have-unequal-space-below-heading) I have extended the example with a TOC. I use the etoc package in my document and the KOMA option `parskip=half` changes the vertical spacing between the TOC chapter title and the TOC entries. The spacing of LOF, LOF ... stays the same. How to avoid this incompatibility? The images should illustrate the problem. Thank you very much in advance!

[image]

Edit: I compile with xelatex

MWE:

```
\documentclass[
    10pt,
    oneside,
    listof=totoc,
    bibliography=totoc,
]{scrbook}

\usepackage{scrhack}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{etoc}

\onehalfspacing
\KOMAoptions{parskip=half}

\begin{document}
    \tableofcontents
    \listoffigures
    \listoftables
    \lstlistoflistings
    \chapter{A Chapter}
    \begin{figure}
        \centering\includegraphics[width=0.5\linewidth]{example-image}
        \caption{First figure}
    \end{figure}
    \begin{table}
        \caption{First table}
        \centering
        \begin{tabular}[width=0.5\linewidth]{ccc}
            Cell 1 & Cell 2 & Cell 3
        \end{tabular}
    \end{table}
    \begin{lstlisting}[caption={First listing}]
        Some code
    \end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the lists under control of `tocbasic` (lof, lot, lol) a final `\parskip` is inserted before  paragraph spacing is switched off. This insertation can be disabled by

```latex
\doforeachtocfile{\setuptoc{#1}{noparskipfake}}
```

But then you have  have less vertical space between the list heading and first entry than between normal chapter headings and normal text.

So it would be better to add this final `\parskip` before  paragraph spacing is switched off to the table of contents (toc) which is under control of `etoc`. The `\etocscrbookstyle` does not take this `\parskip` into account. But you can patch `\etocscrbookstyle` to add the code related to this `\parskip` (coppied from `tocbasic`):

```latex
\usepackage{xpatch}
\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd{\etocscrbookstyle}
  {\setlength {\parskip }{\z@ }}
  {%
    \etoc@Iftocfeature{\@currext}{noparskipfake}{}{%
      \ifvmode
        \@tempskipa\lastskip
        \vskip-\lastskip
        \addtolength{\@tempskipa}{\parskip}%
        \vskip\@tempskipa
      \fi
    }%
    \setlength {\parskip }{\z@ }%
  }{}{\PatchFailed}
\makeatother

\etocstandarddisplaystyle
```

Example:

```latex
\documentclass[
  10pt,
  oneside,
  listof=totoc,
  bibliography=totoc,
]{scrbook}

\usepackage{scrhack}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{etoc}

\onehalfspacing
\KOMAoptions{parskip=half}

\usepackage{xpatch}
\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd{\etocscrbookstyle}
  {\setlength {\parskip }{\z@ }}
  {%
    \etoc@Iftocfeature{\@currext}{noparskipfake}{}{%
      \ifvmode
        \@tempskipa\lastskip
        \vskip-\lastskip
        \addtolength{\@tempskipa}{\parskip}%
        \vskip\@tempskipa
      \fi
    }%
    \setlength {\parskip }{\z@ }%
  }{}{\PatchFailed}
\makeatother

\etocstandarddisplaystyle

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
\listoftables
\lstlistoflistings
\chapter{A Chapter}
Some text
\begin{figure}
  \centering\includegraphics[width=0.5\linewidth]{example-image}
  \caption{First figure}
\end{figure}
\begin{table}
  \caption{First table}
  \centering
  \begin{tabular}[width=0.5\linewidth]{ccc}
    Cell 1 & Cell 2 & Cell 3
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\begin{lstlisting}[caption={First listing}]
  Some code
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Perfect solution and in-depth explanation. Thanks!